# Client Error (400) when deploying application to app engine via eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am new to Google App Engine and I am trying to deploy my application via eclipse. The problem I get when I try to deploy my application is that it gives me the following error:

Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=Project&version=1&
400 Bad Request
Client Error (400)
The request is invalid for an unspecified reason.
See the deployment console for more details
Unable to update app: Error posting to

When I look into the link provided by the console I get the following : 
Unable to update:
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=Project&version=1&
400 Bad Request

Client Error (400)
The request is invalid for an unspecified reason.

```
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send1(AbstractServerConnection.java:293)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send(AbstractServerConnection.java:253)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.post(AbstractServerConnection.java:232)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.ResourceLimits.remoteRequest(ResourceLimits.java:171)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.ResourceLimits.request(ResourceLimits.java:138)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:366)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:53)
at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.proxy.AppEngineBridgeImpl.deploy(AppEngineBridgeImpl.java:433)
at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.DeployProjectJob.runInWorkspace(DeployProjectJob.java:148)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Can anybody please give me some guidance to resolve this problem, so that I can deploy my application? Any feedback will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does it run locally in eclipse?

Is you appengine-web.xml set up correctly with your registered application id?

[Google Getting Started Guide Here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating)

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you for getting back to me.