# Google App Engine Deploy Fails Today

Tags: android-studio, google-app-engine, deployment

I am using Android Studio for a few years now to update a little Java application on Google App Engine. I am on AS 3.1.2 right now.

Occasional I do updates. Yesterday (2018-05-27 12:00 CEST) deployment still worked fine. Today (2018-05-28 9:00 CEST) I changed a few lines of Java code and in `appengine-web.xml` I upgraded `<version>...</version>`. Today I cannot deploy. Build works, locally running application runs, however when I deploy to Google App Engine, I see the following failure 4 times, then deployment is being canceled:

```
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/deploy?app_id=XXX&version=49-storageGap&
400 Bad Request
<ApiError 400, Message: "The request is invalid.">
```

(XXX is not the name of the app, I just thought I hide it here, the name is fine).

Did not help:

- [Client Error (400) when deploying application to app engine via eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15499761/client-error-400-when-deploying-application-to-app-engine-via-eclipse)
- [Unable to Deploy Android App Engine Project on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879197/unable-to-deploy-android-app-engine-project-on-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 2):

Every 20 months I fall to the same issue: No UPPERCASE letters in version. Sorry guys. Renaming to `<version>49-storage-gap</version>` fixed everything.